# Children's book about a strange pet, possibly named "Ham Ham"

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I remember a book I read as a youngster and would like to identify it.

The premise is that a family somehow finds a pet (that was named ham ham or similar) that is sized like a football and is hairy and is able to fly or levitate. It has above-average intelligence - certainly higher that a dog.

One day they visit the park and some scientists abduct it and the family is devastated.

The book was first published at least 25 years ago.

Comment: What's "Ham-ham?"

Comment: Ham ham or similar is the name of the pet.

Comment: Possibly of relevance... I don't know about him levitating, but [Hamtaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamtaro) is what immediately leapt to mind -- the other Hamsters were referred to as the 'Ham Hams.'